# How do I finish E.T for the Atari 2600?

Tags: e.t.-the-extra-terrestrial

I've just bought E.T. and I can't figure out how to play it. I fall into holes all the time and get stuck there. I think this game has potential but I need some help to finish it.

Answer (score 4):

The goal of the game is to find the three pieces of the interplanetary phone at, call back the alien ship that dropped E.T. on Earth, and get picked up at the landing zone.

In order to successfully accomplish this, you'll have to use your various powers, available by standing in specific zones. The icon in the center of the bar at the top of the screen displays what kind of power zone you're standing in at any given time. You can activate these powers by pressing the button on your controller.

The most important power, the "Find phone piece" power is shown as a question mark. When using this power, one of the wells in the area will glow to mean that a phone piece is inside. You can then fall into the well, collect the piece, and levitate out by using the power button again.

Once you have collected all three pieces, you can phone home by activating your power while standing in a "Call ship" zone, shown as an alien figure reminiscent of the enemies in [Space Invaders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Invaders).

After calling the alien ship, a timer will appear in the right part of the top bar, ticking down until the ship's arrival. In order to be picked up, you need to stand in the landing zone, located somewhere in the forest where you start the game. The icon for the landing zone looks one square with a smaller square inside, joined together by thin lines. If you're standing in the right place when the timer reaches zero, E.T. will be picked up and will leave Earth for good.

---

> I think this game has potential

No, it really does not.